# Pivot arrays in DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can the numpy arrays in column B of the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2],"B":[np.asarray([1,2],dtype=float),np.asarray([3,4],dtype=float)]})

print(df)
   A           B
0  1  [1.0, 2.0]
1  2  [3.0, 4.0]
```

be pivoted, such that the resulting df looks like

```
print(df_result)
   A  B
0  1  1.0
1     2.0
2  2  3.0
3     4.0
```

?